# Compositor Blur unexpected result

Tags: compositing-nodes, blur

I try to blur a circle. I make ellipse and plop it in the corner.
After applying blur, I get this result of seemingly X and Y directions getting more blurred than any other.

result:

[image: Picture showing weird cross output of blurred circle]

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong here, but in connection with your exposure and the positioning of the `Ellipse Mask` only the unattractive aspect of *Fast Gaussian* comes to the fore.
In this case, the white areas are more prominent horizontally and vertically, because they are more prominent starting from the upper left corner.

You can avoid this by using a different algorithm for your `Blur`, for example *Gaussian*, or by correcting the exposure.

Comment: Thanks for solution! Yes, my exposure was over 5, setting it to 1 made the result as expected